# Tire tread difference on bmw 328xi

Tags: tires, transmission, bmw, awd

Recently bought a 2007 BMW 328xi awd and the tread on the tires are different. This concerns me because I’ve heard that that is bad and I don’t want any issues down the road. How bad is that on this type of car? We are going to replace the tires either way but I don’t want to be installing a new transmission in a couple months either.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!